# database design for user subscriptions

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

So I'm new to databases in the scope of the subject and looking for some advice for what I am sure is fairly simple. first I'm using MySql as my db I currently have two tables one for storing user accounts and details :

```
TABLE user
id | username | password | email_address | user_devices | contact_method
```

and another for storing video content by producers which looks like:

```
TABLE series
id | series_title | still_broadcasting | last_updated |
```

I would like to implement a feature where Users can select series which they wish to be notified of when new releases are made available and also select how to be notified about these releases (email or push notification ) and how often to be notified (on arrival, hourly, daily, weekly ) I am wondering whats the best way to go about doing this?

I've thought of these ideas by myself but am looking for a second opinion/ better way altogether: (all ideas minus 4 involve storing how to notify user along with how often in user table)

1. adding a text column to user table called following and just having csv's for each series
2. adding multiple boolean column's to user table one for each series
3. adding text column to series table with csv's of user's Id numbers following series
4. creating an entirely new table for notifications though i don't really see the purpose of this as its very redundant

I then plan to just add cron jobs to my server to actually go about regulaurly sending notifications to user's

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is **exactly** the **specific** question or problem you need help for?

Comment: I'm desiging a prototype for a web service i am attempting to make ... I think the rest is explanatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it might be worth giving some articles on basic database design a read.  A quick google turned up this which covers identifying relationships

http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html

Your best bet is to use a linking table i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE userHasSeries (
    userID INT,
    seriesID INT 
);
```

This can then be used in an INNER JOIN query to get the users choices.  What you are doing here is an n:m link between 2 tables.  An example inner join would be

```
SELECT
    u.id AS userID,
    u.username,
    s.seriesID,
    s.series_title,
    s.still_broadcasting,
    s.last_updated
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN userHasSeries AS uhs
    ON uhs.userID = u.id
INNER JOIN series AS s
    ON s.id = uhs.seriesID
```

If users.user_devices  is also a comma seperated list I would advise heavily that you adopt a similar n:m approach there also.

Comment: thanks a lot simon i will do this. I assume by your heavy recommendation that csv's are not recommended in database's (which really would make alot of sense). Also I like your answer alot I'm going to leave the question open to see if anything else turns up but what you've said makes sense to me (minus all the db lingo which ill learn)

Comment: The short answer is that using a comma seperated list is generally a bad idea as it makes doing anything within a query very inefficient compared to joining onto a link table (as this does).  It may be worth trying to read through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization while you're at it for more information on normalisation (which is what this is)

Comment: okay ... and i've been over that wikipedia page in the past, but it could probably use a re-read. What do you think of @dany answer it's much more simple to implement and for that reason I'm leaning towards it

Comment: That's precisely what I meant by my last line, break out the list of devices into the 2 seperate tables, 1 containing 1 row per unique device, and one containing 1 row per user-device link

Comment: alright thanks again! will this table be cascaded? ie. will a change to user or series table be reflected here in the link table (I appologize for my little understanding on the subject) is there a way to cast multiple rep votes as well you could use them

Comment: The link table(s) contain ONLY the id's which relate to PRIMARY KEY's only.  You do not have ANY of the data (i.e. username, device name, series name) in the link tables, only that user ID 1 likes series id 4.  Therefore there is no data that needs cascading, as the retrieval of specific data is done via INNER JOIN queries and so it always queries the data tables which should be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would add a third table as following:

```
TABLE user
id | username | password | email_address | user_devices | contact_method |notification_type

TABLE series
id | series_title | still_broadcasting | last_updated

TABLE followings
id | user_id | series_id
```

In notification_type I would put (on arrival, hourly, daily, or weekly), now in the followings tables I will store all the user's preferred series.

Doing this way makes easy to add, delete, update, or select all user's preferred series. All will be simple  SQL queries. Also you avoid parsing comma separated strings.

for example, if you want to get all preferred series of an user:

```
SELECT * FROM followings AS f INNER JOIN series AS s ON f.series_id = s.id WHERE f.user_id = ?
```

if want to get all users that prefer a serie:

```
SELECT * FROM followings AS f INNER JOIN user AS u ON f.user_id = u.id WHERE f.series_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer which complements what has been written in other answers:

Don't keep a list of devices in the 'user_devices' field - break this out into a separate table. In fact, you'll need two tables: one to list the various devices, and one a join table which has two fields: user_id and device_id. This will enable you to track which user has which device, but also to provide a list of users per device.

Comment: thanks for the input ill be sure to implement this in as well